# Uniform Continuity of functions and their restrictions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f$ is a function mapping a set $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
$A \subseteq S$. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$, how would I show that the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Having the word "set" in the question does not automatically make it about set theory.

Comment: This follows trivially from the definition. Why don't you try it first yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Write the definition of the uniform continuity of $f$ and just  in 
$$\forall \epsilon>0.....,\forall x,y\in S,|x-y|<\delta..............$$
replace $S$ by $A$.

Comment: So it is enough to just say that since A is a subset of S, that showing the definition of uniform continuity in regards to the subset A, that the restriction is uniformly continuous? I thought there had to be more to it?

Comment: Yes since if $x,y\in A$ with some condition then $x,y\in S$ with the same condition.

Comment: Nice work here!

Answer (score 0):

Just verify it by definition. For a given $\varepsilon>0$, the *same* $\delta$ will work as for $f$.